# Find Data between two consecutive nans

Tags: pandas, data-processing

So I have time series data that I do some calculations on it. I am stuck at trying to find a way to get the values of dates between nan points in the series.

For example, the series looks like this:

```
            start_date  counts
3  2021-10-14 20:12:13       0
4  2021-10-14 20:21:10       1
5  2021-10-14 20:22:15       2
6  2021-10-14 20:23:14       3
7  2021-10-14 20:23:51       4
8  2021-10-14 20:39:11       0
9  2021-10-14 20:41:21       1
10 2021-10-14 20:41:45       2
11 2021-10-14 20:42:10       3
12 2021-10-14 20:46:10       4
13 2021-10-14 20:52:53       5
14 2021-10-14 20:53:10       6
15 2021-10-14 20:56:10       7
16 2021-10-14 20:57:46       8
17 2021-10-14 20:59:25       9
18 2021-10-14 21:00:12      10
19 2021-10-14 21:02:24      11
20 2021-10-14 21:06:13      12
21 2021-10-14 21:09:12      13
22 2021-10-14 21:11:35      14
23 2021-10-14 21:16:30      15
24 2021-10-14 21:19:12      16
25 2021-10-14 21:32:14       0
29 2021-10-14 23:52:07       0
30 2021-10-14 23:57:41       1
31 2021-10-15 00:06:14       2
32 2021-10-15 00:23:25       0
33 2021-10-15 00:32:09       1
34 2021-10-15 00:54:11       0
35 2021-10-15 01:03:13       1
```

I want to get the date of the first element ( always = 1) right next to date of the last element (16 in this case but could be any number more than 1)

So the desired output should be :

```
2021-10-14 20:41:21 : 2021-10-14 21:19:12 
.
.
etc.
```

Comment: use df['colname_with_nan'].isna().cumsum(), this will give you a value for the first NAN up to the next NAN.... So if you just want the values between the first nan and the second nan find where the above expression equals to 1.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
# Extract a subset of your dataframe with a clean index
df1 = df.reset_index()[['start_date', 'counts']]

# Detect 2 consecutive 0 (or NaN?) and get previous row
idx2 = df1.loc[df1['counts'].eq(0)
               & df1['counts'].shift(-1).eq(0), 'counts'].index - 1

# Find the counts of the row then subtract to idx2
idx1 = idx2 - df1.loc[idx2, 'counts'].values + 1

# Join the 2 indexes
out = pd.concat([df1.loc[idx1, 'start_date'].reset_index(drop=True),
                 df1.loc[idx2, 'start_date'].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
           start_date          start_date
0 2021-10-14 20:41:21 2021-10-14 21:19:12
```